# How to copy scheduled task in plesk

Tags: cron, copy, task, plesk

Plesk version: 11.5.30

I want to copy 4 scheduled tasks from one website to 31 other websites in Plesk.
How can this be done? 
I can not find any copy / paste function. If I have to do this by hand it will take somewhile.

Example of a task I want to copy:

```
Switched on
Min: 10
Hour: 2
DM: *
M: *
DW: *
Command: /usr/bin/wget -O/dev/null -q http://www.mywebsite.nl/emailservice/script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use crontabmng utility. All necessary options you can find with

/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/crontabmng --help

Pay your attention on 'set' option.